# Table error: Missing number treated as zero

Tags: tables, missing, number, measure

When making a table in Latex with "tabular", I always get the following errors:

- "Missing number, treated as zero \begin{tabular}"
- "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \begin{tabular}"

This is the table:

```
\\
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\caption{xx}
\footnotesize
\textwidth
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{1}   & \textbf{1}        & \textbf{3}     & \4       & 5      & 6      & 7       \\ \hline \hline
a        & b             & c              & d              & e             & f             & g              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the '\textwidth' from your code.

Comment: Could you explain me please what \textwidth is exactly doing and why it leads to the error? I had used it because I tried to put the table to fit the width of my text, but this attempt failed :(

Comment: The _\textwidth_ command is used, if you use e. g. the tabularx-package like this: 
\begin{tabularx}[>width< (e.g. \textwidth]
... tablecode
\end{tabularx}
Then, the table can be fit to the text. This is exceptionally useful, when you have a document with more than one column.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, thank you! I got confused with the different table packages, as I am quite new to LaTex.